# Vector multiplication of squared vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors, hadamard-product

I would like to have a mathematical expression for this problem:

A = [n x 1] (i.e. 1;2;3)
B = [n x 1] (i.e. 4;5;6)

I'm looking for the dot multiplication of both vectors pointwise-squared.

```
c = A^2*B^2
```

The answer should be a scalar with a value of 440
The matlab expression looks like:

```
c = ([1;2;3].^2)'*([4;5;6].^2) = 440
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Comment: "I would like to have a mathematical expression for this equation" Where is "this equation"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\circ$ denote the hadamard product.

$$\sum_{i=1}^nA_i^2B_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(A_iB_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (A \circ B)_i^2=\left\|A \circ B\right\|_2^2$$